# javascript: full-width centered animated slider

Tags: javascript, slider, settimeout

I'm trying to make a button-controlled slider using javascript. I have a full-width div, with a large background image. I want the background image to move left and right on clicks. So far I've managed to do that, the problem is getting it to stop at the right position.

I'm controlling the animation with setTimeout, using % instead of px because I want the background image to start of centered.. at 50%. Now I need it to move a 1000px left or right, depending on what button I click. I also need to prevent the buttons from increasing the speed of the animation on every click.

As far as I understand this can be done using clearTimeout. I haven't found a good way of writing this tho so I'm looking for help or a push in the right direction. Thank you.

Code below:

index.html

```
<!doctype html>  
<html>  
        <head> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css"/>
    </head>  
    <body>
        <div id="top">
            <div id="top_center"></div>
        </div>
            <div id="header">
                <div id="button_container">
                    <div id="button_left">
                        <a href="#" class="links"> < <a/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="button_right">
                        <a href="#" class="links"> > <a/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div id="bottom">
            <div id="bottom_center"></div>
        </div>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="slider.js"></script>        
    </body>  
</html>
```

slider.js

```
var slider = {

    init: function(){

        var header = document.getElementById("header");
        header.style.backgroundPosition = "50%";
        var timeout;

        var button_left = document.getElementById("button_left");
        var button_right = document.getElementById("button_right");

        button_left.onclick = function(){

            header.style.backgroundPosition = parseInt(header.style.backgroundPosition) + 1 + '%';
            timeout = setTimeout(button_left.onclick, 20);          
        }

        button_right.onclick = function(){

            header.style.backgroundPosition = parseInt(header.style.backgroundPosition) - 1 + "%";
            timeout = setTimeout(button_right.onclick, 20);
        }
    }
}
window.onload = slider.init;
```

Well, i solved this little pickle using jQuery as John Fisher suggested. I used this [tutorial](http://youtu.be/gZ9Km3bPte0) by Harry Finn. I had to do some modifications to his code and css but it turned out the way I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing animation, why not use JQuery or one of the other javascript libraries that handle automation for you.  They handle a lot of little details that are time-consuming to manage on your own.

Comment: I have no experience with jQuery or any other library. I will have to use them if this really turns out to be a lot of trouble, most questions to this kind of stuff do seem to be jQuery related. It would be great to learn how to do this with just javascript, the information seems to be hard to find tho.

Comment: You can pick up the JQuery library and look at it's code.  It would show you some of the techniques for doing animation through setTimeout().